# serviceworker.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed .Net Core 3.1

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to create a PWA from a simple Asp.Net Core 3.1 application with Razor Pages. The manifest file works fine, the service worker registers fine, but gives the following error:
sw.js: 1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed.

Can anyone help me solve it?

Attached image of the error:

Thanks in advance

The code for service worker I have obtained from the following url:
https://www.spheregen.com/implementing-pwa-behavior-to-asp-net-mvc-5-apps/

And it is the same as:
https://gist.github.com/TanmaySM/33118c2366fa544fb08197bcb770f9ef#file-serviceworker-js

[service worker error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxANq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest.json or your appsettings.json if you are catching a url that doesnt exist!

That worked for me :)